# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined in react native This is working properly in app js but not in about js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Code working properly in App.js but not in About.js

I tried everything which I find in google, But it always gives me "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined.

How could I solve this?
Please help me out from this issue.
Your help will be appreciated and if need more information then please let me know

**App.js**

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
  },
  Audios: {
    screen: FouraudioScreen,
  },
  About: {
    screen: AboutScreen,
    navigationOptions : {
        header: null
    }
  },
   Gallery: {
    screen: GalleryScreen,
    navigationOptions : {
        header: null
    }
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color:'#1c2747',
   // alignItems: 'center',
    //justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }  
}
```

// **About.js**

```
render() {
   return (

        <View> 
            <Button
            title="Go to Gallery"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Gallery')}
          />
        </View>
   )
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    About: {
      screen: AboutScreen,
    },
    Gallery: {
      screen: GalleryScreen,
    },
  },
   {
  headerMode: 'none', 

  }
);

const AboutContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AboutScreen />;
  }
};

export default About;
```

Comment: try with this.props.navigation.navigate

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ,Tried this also please read edited code.

Comment: class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AboutScreen navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
  }
};

try this

Comment: Same error . And I'm console.log(this.props) in render function then giving me the this output like  ** {navigation: undefined}
navigation: undefined
__proto__: Object **

Comment: What is that render() outside of About class in About.js?

Comment: @DominikMatis  render function for AboutScreen class which is navigate through Stack navigator "About".

Comment: Change AboutScreen to AboutContainer

Comment: @Manoj you have variable called AboutContainer but you are using AboutScreen, fix it

Comment: @DominikMatis You have the right point and Now props are comming there but my  AboutScreen class render functions code not appearing in output.

Comment: @DominikMatis   Thanks, other issue persisting from my styling.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your class in About.js as AboutScreen , so that when `AboutScreen` is loaded by the StackNavigator, it will be given a `navigation` prop.

Answer (score 0):

**Add 
`import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';`
to your About.js and export that class as
 `export default withNavigation(About.js)`**

Comment: **Same error**
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AboutScreen />;
  }
};


export default withNavigation(About);

When i'm doing export default withNavigation(About.js); then showing display name error.

Comment: I think you need to make your code cleaner and describe it a little better to properly understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library for handling navigation problem and also prevent the usage of this.props.navigation prop.

### [React Navigation Helpers](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-navigation-helpers)

Usage is very simple. On your App.js or your navigator simply set the global level navigator.

```
import NavigationService from "react-navigation-helpers";


<MainNavigator
  ref={navigatorRef =>
    NavigationService.setGlobalLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)
  }
/>
```

Then you use ANYWHERE on your project with this simple code segment:

```
NavigationService.navigate("home")
```

Of course, you still need to import the NavigationService :)

You can find a more detailed document on the library's README. If you still have a question, feel free to ask, I will help you gladly.